# Why does the .scrollHeight works the way it does?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight)
```

I mean, why do we need to specify [0] after the selected element. What does it indicate? It seems not to be indicating the children of the div element, since [1] is undefined even though there are more children. And if I alert(('#div1')[0]) it says [object HTMLDivElement].
I actually never saw this kind of indexing in jQuery. So I'd like to know what this index zero indicates and in what other cases it is used? I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: `scrollHeight` is a DOM property, jQuery is array like object, `$('#div1')[0]` returns the first DOM element matched by selector passed to jQuery, etc...

Comment: I see that it's a property, not a method certainly. But it is a property not of the div element but of $('#div1')[0] element. That's what I not understand. What does that zero index stands for?

Comment: jQuery places the elements in a custom array-like object. When you want to work with the native DOM node, you can get it by accessing the jQuery object like an array, hence `$('#div1')[0]` is exactly the same as `document.getElementById('div1')` in this case

Comment: But since the element is selected by id, why the heck do we need to specify that it is the first element? We do not do this for all the other cases in jQuery, why now? Why in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.scrollHeight` **is *not* a jQuery's method**: http://api.jquery.com/scrollHeight/
***[Element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight)*** is a **JavaScript** method that returns

> *the height of an element's content, including content not visible on the screen due to overflow*

Due you're passing your selector `"#div1"` to the jQuery Object `$(    )`,
**it'll return an *Array Object collection* of HTMLElements**.

```
$('#div1') // [object Object] { 0: [object HTMLDivElement] { ...obj props...}}
              ^--Object Array   ^--key 0   ^--Element Obj. ^--Obj. properties
```

therefore

```
[object Object].scrollHeight    // undefined
```

but if you reach from that Array the `[0]`th *key* representing the **HTMLDivElement**:

```
[object Object][0].scrollHeight // 800
```

you have than accessible the needed Object properties `{...obj props...}` for that specific Element where `scrollHeight` is one of them.

**To recap**,

(JS):

```
var el = document.getElementById("div1"); // HTMLDivElement
var sh = el.scrollHeight;                 // 800
```

(jQuery)

```
var el = $("#div1");                      // Object Array (note the difference)
var sh = el.scrollHeight;                 // undefined
var sh = el[0].scrollHeight;              // 800
```

To get an element's `scrollHeight` in **plain jQuery** <sup>(v.1.6+)</sup> you can do

```
var sh = $("#div1").prop('scrollHeight'); // 800
```